# datatables editor: presubmit password encryption

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

This question might be a how to proceed in JavaScript. My issue is that before submitting (`preSubmit`) to save the password I encrypt it via an AJAX call. This works fine. I get back the encrypted password.

However outside the callback I don't have it, I also tried an `ajaxStop` (see snippet) but I don't know if this is really the problem.

Thus inside the callback I have the right encrypted password, outside, afterwards I only have the plain password. What I am doing wrong?

```js
editorBenutzerU.on('preSubmit', function(e, d) {
  if (!d.data.benutzer.passwort) {
    delete d.data.benutzer.passwort;
  } else {
    var password;
    var url = "json-save-password.php?pass=" + d.data.benutzer.passwort;
    $(document).ajaxStop(function() {
      $.post(
        url,
        function(data) {
          password = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
          d.data.benutzer.passwort = password; //encrypted
          return password;
        });
    });
    $(this).unbind('ajaxStop');
    //unfortunately d.data.benutzer.passwort is plain here
  }
});
```

Comment: Update: I am using a setFormatter (http://editor.datatables.net/manual/php/formatters) now to do the hashing of the password. The Ajax call is not necessary any more. Solved the issue by using a different and more elegant way

Comment: You can answer your own question here, please share your solution if you can as an answer.